# WordPress scheduled event is not actually scheduling

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I'm trying to get my cron to work in my plugin with this code:

```
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'my_thing' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'my_thing' );
    }
add_action( 'my_thing', 'action_to_take' );


function action_to_take() {
    // do something
}
```

...but it doesn't appear to be scheduling like the other cron jobs are. When I check the crons using a 3rd party tool (WP Crontrol), I can see the cron but the '**Next Run**' status is always '**now**' instead of about an hour from now:

[image]

I've seen this question asked [on another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48747650/the-next-run-in-wp-crontrol-plug-in-is-not-working), and the only response appears to be the same way I have done it (even though it's not labelled as the answer).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you schedule any event with current time then it will run first time immediately to set the next cron

Comment: Yes, and the Next Run time should be about an hour. If I refresh the page, it's always 'now'.

Comment: No that's not like that I have tried your same code you may check this snap - http://prntscr.com/qysnar

Comment: Interesting. That's given me a new line of debugging to look at - thanks. It must be something else in my plug-in that's causing it to always be 'now'. I'll report back later.